# Multi dimension array splice return nested array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have 2 2D array, and want to merge a[0] with b[0]

```
var a=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]];
var b=[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];

console.log(a[0].splice(1,2,b[0]));
its return ["a",["1","2","3"]]

i need to archive ["a","1","2","3"] for a[0]
```

can any body show how ?

Comment: what should be the value for a[0][1] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From **docs**, syntax of [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])

As you can see, you can add more than 1 element to the array e.g. `arr.splice(0,0,4,5)` where you are adding 2 values (4 & 5) into array. With `b[0]` as 3rd parameter, you are adding the whole array at a particular index. To add individual value, you need to spread the values of array. You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax) for that. With that `arr.splice(0,0,...[1,2])` will become `arr.splice(0,0,1,2)`

```js
var a=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]];
var b=[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];
a[0].splice(1,2,...b[0])
console.log(a[0]);
```

Comment: this is work, but i don't understand about 3 dot ?, can you give me link where i can get more insight about it
Translate instead ok this is work but i dont understain about 3 dot ?, can you give me link where i can get more insign about it

Comment: @RioArfani - I have added some details. please see if it answers your query

Comment: @RioArfani - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Syntax)

> Spread syntax allows an iterable to expand in places where 0+
>   arguments are expected.

```js
var a=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"]];
var b=[["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"]];

//if you are trying to achieve all elements in single array then
var result = [...a[0], ...b[0]];
console.log(result);

//if you are trying to achieve single element from first array and all from other then
var result = [...a[0][0], ...b[0]];
console.log(result);
```

Good article on [Spread syntax](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754)